# How to pass a constant array as argument to a C++ function/method

Tags: c++, arrays, arguments, cimg

**Problem:**
I have a C++11 method (CImg class) that takes in input an `unsigned char[3]` array to specify the color. I'm compiling with a mingw compiler and `-std=gnu++11` option.
For reference this is the method I need to call:

```cpp
template<typename tc>
CImg<T>& draw_line(int x0, int y0, int x1, int y1, const tc *const color, const float opacity=1, const unsigned int pattern=~0U, const bool init_hatch=true);
```

If I try to construct the array locally I get the following error. The array is created and destroyed before being passed, making the argument invalid when the function is called.

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, (unsigned char[3]){0,255,0}, 0.9 );
"ERROR: taking address of temporary array"
```

**Attempt 2: Local array declared before function call using local var**
Researching the issue, the most common solution is to create an explicit local var. It clearly works since it's destroyed later, when it goes out of scope. It obviously works, but I really feel there *should* be a more readable and less verbose way of doing it.

```cpp
unsigned char my_temp_color[3] = {0,255,0};
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, my_temp_color, 0.9 );
```

**Attempt 3: Constant local array**
I fooled around with different ways to pass the array. I tried with structures, etc...
My mingw compiler is happy with passing a local constant array and does not give any warnings or errors.

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, (const unsigned char[3]){0,255,0}, 0.9 );
```

**Proposed Solution 1: std::array**
If I try passing a naked std::array, the compiler cannot resolve the type to unsigned char[3]

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::array<unsigned char,3>{ {0,255,0} }, 0.9 );
"error: no matching function for call to 'cimg_library::CImg<float>::draw_line(int, int, int, int, std::array<unsigned char, 3>, double)"
```

It works if I pass a local std::array using .data() method to get the pointer, but it is even more verbose than a regular array.

```cpp
std::array<unsigned char,3> my_temp_color = { {0,255,0} };
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, my_temp_color.data(), 0.9 );
```

It works if I do it all inline. With this solution I'm not sure on where the object is created/destroyed and I'm worried about the pointer becoming invalid and passing trash data silently.

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::array<unsigned char,3>{ {0,255,0} }.data(), 0.9 );
```

**Proposed Solution 2: std::string**
The initialization is harder to read with std::string. If I try passing a naked std::string, the compiler cannot resolve the type to unsigned char[3]

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::string("/0/255/0"), 0.9 );
"no matching function for call to 'cimg_library::CImg<float>::draw_line(int, int, int, int, std::__cxx11::string, double)'"
```

Like std::array it works if I i use .data() method, but I have the same worries.

**Proposed Solution 3: wrapper + structures**
The third solution proposed by @jarod42 is to create wrappers around the third party library and use a more convenient and readable interface. Being able to change the interface allows to use structures that solve all problems of scoping and temporary values. It also has the added benefit of adding an abstraction layer and making future changes easier. I decided to incapsulate wrappers and structures as static methods inside a class. I really like this solution.

The `using` statement can be used to make the code less verbose. My compiler can also automatically deduce the type from just the brackets. For the scope of this question I left it extended to understand what's going on.

```cpp
//Build option:
//-std=gnu++11

//STD
#include <string>
//CImg
#define cimg_use_png
#define cimg_display 0
#include "CImg.h"
using namespace cimg_library;
//PNG library
#include "png.h"

//CImg wrapper. Add an abstraction layer to CImg to use less verbose Point and Color structures
class CImg_wrapper
{
    public:
        //2D Point
        typedef struct _Point_2d
        {
            int g_s32_x, g_s32_y;
        } Point_2d;
        //3 channel color
        typedef struct _Color_3u8
        {
            unsigned char g_u8p_rgb[3];
        } Color_3u8;
        //Draw text on an image
        template<typename T>
        static void draw_text(CImg<T>& image, Point_2d origin, std::string text, Color_3u8 foreground_color, float opacity, int font_size )
        {
            image.draw_text(origin.g_s32_x, origin.g_s32_y, text.c_str(), foreground_color.g_u8p_rgb, 0, opacity, font_size);
            return;
        }
        //Draw a line on an image
        template<typename T>
        static void draw_line(CImg<T>& image, Point_2d p1, Point_2d p2, Color_3u8 color, float transparency)
        {
            image.draw_line(p1.g_s32_x, p1.g_s32_y, p2.g_s32_x, p2.g_s32_y, color.g_u8p_rgb, transparency);
            return;
        }
};  //CImg_wrapper

//DEMO
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Create image
    CImg<float> image
    (
        //width
        200,
        //height
        100,
        //Depth. 1 for a 2D image
        1,
        //Number of channels
        3
    );
    //draw text on the image
    CImg_wrapper::draw_text(image, (CImg_wrapper::Point_2d){20, 10}, std::string("Shaka"), (CImg_wrapper::Color_3u8){0,0,255}, 0.9f, 24 );
    //draw a line on the image
    CImg_wrapper::draw_line(image, (CImg_wrapper::Point_2d){20, 90}, (CImg_wrapper::Point_2d){190, 10}, (CImg_wrapper::Color_3u8){0,255,0}, 0.9f );
    //The compiler is able to deduce the type from just the brackets if needed
    //CImg_wrapper::draw_line(image, {20, 90}, {190, 10}, {0,255,0}, 0.9f );
    //Save image on file
    image.save("file.png");

    return 0;
}
```

output:
[image: Output PNG image]

source code:
https://github.com/OrsoEric/2021-02-02-CImg-PNG-Test

**Questions:**

1. Is passing `(const unsigned char[3]){0,255,0}` C++11 compliant or it's just a quirk of the mingw compiler that makes it work?
2. Is there another way I have not considered to declare and pass the array as argument?
3. With the following calls are the temporary objects destroyed after the statement (safe), or before the call (causing the pointer to potentially become invalid)?

```cpp
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::array<unsigned char,3>{ {0,255,0} }.data(), 0.9 );
image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::string("/0/255/0").data(), 0.9 );
```

Comment: What about `std::array`?

Comment: I would consider adding class for Color, Point.

Comment: Thanks. 'tc' s just a template, I forgot to add it. I edited the question.

Comment: I just tried `std::array` `error: no matching function for call to 'cimg_library::CImg<float>::draw_line(int, int, int, int, std::array<unsigned char, 3>, double)'`

Comment: @Jarod42 I can't modify the CImg class to accept a different type, and wouldn't using an object have the same problem of it being destroyed before it can be used?

Comment: Write a wrapper then: `template<typename T> draw_line(CImg<T>&, Point p1, Point p2, Color);`

Comment: @Jarod42 I can write both the Classes point and Color and write the wrappers for the methods I need, but wouldn't constructing the object Points inside the call have the same problem of being destroyed before the call?
`draw_line_wrapper(image, Point(20,90), Point( 190,10), Color(0,255,0) );`

Comment: Things like `{0,255,0}` should be named. Don't use magic constants in the code. How about `Green`?

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m I'm a big fan of enumeration too. E.G. I like to add  `typedef enum _Config { MY_PARAM=42 } Config;` to store class parameters. For this question I cut the non relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with 3rd library, it is generally good to write wrapper around them.

- So you might have the interface you want,
- and you might easily change/upgrade the 3rd library if needed (you only have to adapt the wrappers):

```
struct Point
{
   int x = 0;
   int y = 0;
}

struct Color
{
    Color(unsigned char r, unsigned char g, unsigned char b, unsigned char a = 0) :
        rgba{r, g, b, a}
    {}

    // ...
    unsigned char rgba[4]{};
};

template<typename T>
void draw_line(CImg<T>& img, Point p1, Point p2, Color color)
{
    img.draw_line(p1.x, p1.y, p2.x, p2.y, color.rgba);
}
```

And so you might use:

```
draw_line(img, Point{20, 90}, Point{190, 10}, Color{0,255,0});
draw_line(img, {20, 90}, {190, 10}, {0,255,0});
```

Note: You might even hide `CImg<T>` in your own class/interface.

Comment: This works! I edited the question to add my implementation. I decided against using constructor inside structures and I decided to incapsulate the wrappers as static methods inside a wrapper class. Thanks, this solves my problem!

Answer (score 0):

My simple answer is:

Forget about the old C-style arrays. Do not use them at all.

Use `std::array` if you know the size in advance and `std::vector` if you don't.

Especially: Use `std::string` instead of `char[]` or `char*`.

And pass the variables around using references.

Comment: Use `std::string` instead of `char[]` or `char*` makes no sense in the context of the op's code. There isn't an `int8` type in standard C++, so `char` is just the next best thing.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to be working `image.draw_line( 20, 90, 190, 10, std::array<unsigned char,3>{ {0,255,0} }.data(), 0.9 );` Is this correct use? I'm not sure where the object is created/destroyed and where it goes out of scope.

Comment: destroyed to quickly here unfortunately.

Comment: @George There's the (optional but often implemented) `std::(u)int8_t` though, and since C++20, there is `char8_t`, so I'm not sure what you're trying to argue here...

Comment: The advice of using std::array is good, but I don't understand how it would solve the problem of the inline declaration being a temporary object that is destroyed too early.

Comment: @rubenvb Trying to argue that in the context of the op's code using `std::string` is bad advice.